# Cannot install third party library

Tags: ios, xcode, github, libraries

I keep trying to add https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController into my project but it keeps coming up with a linking error.

```
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong I can't seem to add the demo into a blank project and get it to work.

This is what I'm doing:

1. I download the zipfile which contains the demo project folder (not an entire xcode project, just the .h and .m files needed for the demo).
2. I open a blank xcode project and insert the demo project folder.
3. I delete the blank project's plist, storyboard, main and app delegate files.
4. From the terminal, I cd into the project and make a podfile that looks like this:

   ```
   platform :ios, '7.0'
   pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
   pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'
   ```
5. I run pod install.
6. I open the project in its new workspace that has the pods and I try to run it.
7. It throws the linking error.

What step am I missing? I see on the GitHub installation process it says:

```
  #import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>    // import all the things
```

but I don't know what that means. I figured it meant something about updating your headers seach path but when I look at that under Build Settings its already pointing to the header file in the pods.

Is there an obvious step I'm missing when adding a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

I installed JSQMessagesViewController through cocoapods in my project, I did not get any errors successfully installed.Please try the following steps:

1. Open Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your project by using the cd command:

   cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Project
2. Next enter this command: pod init
3. Type this command to open Podfile using Xcode for editing:open -a Xcode Podfile.
4. Copy and paste this line: pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '6.1.3' and save it.
5. Type this command: pod install

This installs dependent libraries related to JSQMessagesViewController and JSQSystemSoundPlayer.
After this close the project and go to your project folder ,use the workspace intead of xcodespace : yourProject.xcworkspace. Hope this post might help you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open a brand new project from Xcode, do not delete anything.

2.cd ~/ROOT_PATH_OF_YOUR_PROJECT

3.Edit your `Podfile` if your already had one

```
Podfile

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'
```

4.run `pod install`

5.open `yourproject.xcworkspace`

6.Build